# Find Sum of Columns of Data in Django Like and Excel File

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am using Django 1.8.3 and Python 3.4.3

Comparing my issue to an Excel file is the best way I can explain my challenge. I have a ListView that is displaying a table of data in my template.  The left column are the months January through December, with value fields across the top (just like an Excel Spreadsheet)  I need to add the value of the "columns" to render a "total" Sum.  I've read several solutions, but I can't seem to figure it out is a Pythonic way.

Below are snippets of my code that will hopefully give you a good idea of what I need to do.

**Solution Needed:** I need to get the total value of each months Recipients table, which will be displayed in a Master matrix (not shown here)

Thank you for your help.  If you do help, please provide template tag example as well.

index.html (Only showing January & February, but the list goes to December)

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Recipients</th>
    <th>Unsubscribes</th>
    <th>Bounces</th>
    <th>Open</th>
    <th>Clicks</th>
    <th>Open Rate</th>
    <th>CTR</th>
    <th>Sales</th>
    <th>IFS SignUps</th>
    <th>Traffic</th>
    <th>T/S Ratio</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    {% if email_list %}
      <td>January</td>
      <td>{{ total_campaigns.January | default_if_none:"0" }}</td>
      <td>{{ total_recipients.January | default_if_none:"0" }}</td>
      <td>{{ total_unsubscribes.January | default_if_none:"0" }}</td>
      <td>{{ total_bounces.January | default_if_none:"0" }}</td>
      <td>{{ total_open.January | default_if_none:"0" }}</td>
      <td>{{ total_clicks.January | default_if_none:"0" }}</td>
      <td>{% average total_open.January total_recipients.January %}</td>
      <td>{% average total_clicks.January total_open.January %}</td>
    {% endif %}
    {% if traffic_list %}
      <td>{{total_sales.January | default_if_none:"0" }}</td>
      <td>{{total_ifs_signups.January | default_if_none:"0" }}</td>
      <td>{{total_traffic.January | default_if_none:"0" }}</td>
      <td>{% ratio total_traffic.January total_sales.January %}</td>
    {% endif %}
  </tr>
  <tr>
    {% if email_list %}
      <td>February</td>
      <td>{{ total_campaigns.February | default_if_none:"0" }}</td>
      <td>{{ total_recipients.February | default_if_none:"0" }}</td>
      <td>{{ total_unsubscribes.February | default_if_none:"0" }}</td>
      <td>{{ total_bounces.February | default_if_none:"0" }}</td>
      <td>{{ total_open.February | default_if_none:"0" }}</td>
      <td>{{ total_clicks.February | default_if_none:"0" }}</td>
      <td>{% average total_open.February total_recipients.February %}</td>
      <td>{% average total_clicks.February total_open.February %}</td>
    {% endif %}
    {% if traffic_list %}
      <td>{{total_sales.February | default_if_none:"0" }}</td>
      <td>{{total_ifs_signups.February | default_if_none:"0" }}</td>
      <td>{{total_traffic.February | default_if_none:"0" }}</td>
      <td>{% ratio total_traffic.February total_sales.February %}</td>
    {% endif %}
  </tr>

  ... ( This repeats through the month of December )
```

views.py ( sample data from my views file )

```
    class DashboardView(TemplateView):
        template_name = "dashboard/pages/index.html"

        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super(DashboardView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['email_list'] = Email.objects.all()
            context['traffic_list'] = Traffic.objects.all()

            days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
            months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October',
                      'November', 'December']

            total_campaigns = {}
            campaign_totals = {}
            total_recipients = {}
            total_unsubscribes = {}
            total_bounces = {}
            total_open = {}
            total_clicks = {}
            total_sales = {}
            total_ifs_signups = {}
            total_traffic = {}

            for month in months:
                # total count
                total_campaigns[month] = Email.objects.filter(month=month).count()
                # recipients
                total_recipients[month] = Email.objects.filter(month=month).aggregate(
                    Sum('recipients')).get('recipients__sum', 0.00)
                # unsubscribes
                total_unsubscribes[month] = Email.objects.filter(month=month).aggregate(
                    Sum('unsubscribes')).get('unsubscribes__sum', 0.00)
                # bounces
                total_bounces[month] = Email.objects.filter(month=month).aggregate(Sum('bounces')).get(
                    'bounces__sum', 0.00)
                # opens
                total_open[month] = Email.objects.filter(month=month).aggregate(
                    Sum('open')).get('open__sum', 0.00)
                # clicks
                total_clicks[month] = Email.objects.filter(month=month).aggregate(
                    Sum('clicks')).get('clicks__sum', 0.00)

...
```

Comment: I would recommend you to combine with Pandas.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I will look closer at this as I get to the second phase of my app and when I am not such a noob...Pandas is a bit over my experience level :)  Thank you.

Comment: Welcome. Actually I would advise you again to take a look at it. It is not as difficult as it seems, and it will definitely save you development time in the mid-long term. When it comes to data analysis, Pandas is cool.

Comment: Why would you need Pandas when you have access to a relational database with all the data in it? Sounds like another unnecessary layer of complexity. This sort of thing should be done at the database level using aggregates. I would use SQL.

Comment: I think I will take another look at Pandas. I rabbit holed a bit last night looking more into it and since my app will eventually deal with many data streams, it might make sense to look closer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Django aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/) support this.

For aggregates grouped by a field, use a [values clause](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/#values)  with `annotate` , for example:

```
>>> from django.db.models import Count, Sum

>>> stats = Email.objects.all().values('month').annotate(
        Count('month'), Sum('recipients'), Sum('unsubscribes'), ...)
>>> stats
[{'month': 'January', 'month__count': 100, 'recipients__sum': 24, ... }
 {'month': 'February', 'month__count': 75, 'recipients__sum': 22, ... }]
```

You can also get totals from the database using `aggregate`:

```
>>> Email.objects.all().aggregate(
        Count(), Sum('recipients'), Sum('unsubscribes'), ...)

{'id__count': 175, 'recipients__sum': 46, ...}
```

However, it may be faster to avoid querying the database again, and calculate totals from what is already in memory (in by-month aggregations):

```
>>> totals = {}
>>> for key in ['month__count', 'recipients__sum', 'unsubscribes__sum', ...]:
...     totals[key] = sum(month.get(key, 0) for month in stats)
```

Comment: This is great, thank you.  

This is the code in my view
`for key in ['month__count', 'recipients__sum', 'unsubscribes__sum']:
stats = Email.objects.all().values('month').annotate(Count('month'), Sum('recipients'), Sum('unsubscribes'),)
totals[key] = sum(month.get(key, 0) for month in stats)`

this is my template tag `{{ totals }}`

but it renders this...I know I am missing something simple
`{'recipients__sum': 7026255, 'month__count': 44, 'unsubscribes__sum': 7701}` How can I just have it render the total of say, recipients?

Comment: Get the desired value from the `totals` dict using a key, like:  `{{ totals.recipients__sum }}`.

Comment: I tried that yesterday and it didn't work and then I just realized the double underscore for the sum. Works brilliantly! Thank you.